# Laravel Storage not saving image

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-7, filepond, laravel-storage

I am trying to save image in storage. Here is my code

```
 public function uploadEducationalInstitutionLogo(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->hasFile('logo')) {

            $file = $request->file('logo');
            $fileName = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();

            $img = Image::make($file);

            $img->fit(820, 312, function (Constraint $constraint) {
                $constraint->upsize();
            });

            Storage::putFileAs('institution-logo', (string)$img->encode(null, 95), $fileName);

            return response()->json([
                'filename' => $fileName
            ]);
        }
    }
```

My request from vue frontend using vue filepond component as my image uploader:

```
 <file-pond
    name="logo"
    allow-multiple="false"
    max-files="1"
    accepted-file-types="image/jpeg, image/png"
    v-bind:files="myFiles"
    :label-idle="label"
    v-on:init="handleFilePondInit"
    v-on:processfile="onload"
    :server="server"
  />
<script>
data() {
    return {
      myFiles: [],
      server: {
        url: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/logo`,
        process: {
          headers: {
            Authorization: localStorage.getItem("access_token"),
          },
        },
      },
    };
  },
<script>
```

Here it's throwing following error:

*ErrorException: fopen() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, string given in file...*

Here is my API request to save image:
[image]

I want to store my pictures in  *storage/images/institution-logo/image.jpg*

Another question is where it will be best to save in:

1)storage/images/..
OR
2)public/storage/images/... ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Have you added `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form?

Comment: please see my edited version @BABAKASHRAFI

Comment: Please add your html form in the question

Comment: Do you send it via ajax(xhr) request?

Comment: see the edited version again please

Answer (score 1):

```php
$data = $request->all();
foreach ($data['logo'] as $imgFile) {
    $imgName = 'logo_' . random_int(111111, 999999) . '.' . $imgFile->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $imgFile->move(storage_path('/images/', $imgName);
}
```

Use move(storage_path);

Comment: Hey @Gevorg, welcome! I tidied up your answer a bit - if you click on edit, you'll see how I've used backticks (`) to format the code to make it easier to read.